Preload Assets using Expo Assets
I am trying to preload an image before my main Layout is rendered but I am still getting a flash of the image background which I have set to red for debugging. Here is my code.
function RootLayout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const { user, userLoading } = useAuth();
  const { languageLoading, getStoredLanguage } = useLanguage();
  const { cityLoading, getStoredCity } = useCity();
  const [assetsLoading, setAssetsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadAssets = async () => {
      try {
        await Asset.loadAsync([require("./assets/images/onboard.jpg")]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      } finally {
        setAssetsLoading(false);
      }
    };
    loadAssets();
  }, []);

  function initializeLayout() {
    Promise.all([getStoredLanguage(), getStoredCity()]).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    initializeLayout();
  }, []);

  if (userLoading || languageLoading || cityLoading || assetsLoading) {
    return <Splash />;
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={colorScheme === "light" ? DefaultTheme : DarkTheme}>
      {user ? <SignedInLayout /> : <AuthLayout />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

RootLayout is rendered in the App component in-between other providers.
Here is my screen from the AuthLayout;
return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingBottom: insets.bottom }}>
      <ImageBackground
        source={require("../../../assets/images/onboard.jpg")}
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red" }}
        contentFit="cover"
      /> ...


You aren't actually using the preloaded value; Asset.loadAsync returns the preloaded value and you never access it. You need to store this value in state and pass it to AuthLayout. The useAssets hook handles this state creation for you:
function RootLayout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const { user, userLoading } = useAuth();
  const { languageLoading, getStoredLanguage } = useLanguage();
  const { cityLoading, getStoredCity } = useCity();
  const [assets, error] = useAssets([require("./assets/images/onboard.jpg")]
  // if there's no error and no assets then assets are loading
  const assetsLoading = !error && !Boolean(assets)


  
  useEffect(() => {
    
    function initializeLayout() {
      Promise.all([getStoredLanguage(), getStoredCity()]).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
    initializeLayout();
  }, []);

  if (userLoading || languageLoading || cityLoading || assetsLoading) {
    return <Splash />;
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={colorScheme === "light" ? DefaultTheme : DarkTheme}>
      {user ? <SignedInLayout /> : <AuthLayout backgroundImage={assets?.[0].localUri}/>}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

AuthLayout:
return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingBottom: insets.bottom }}>
      <ImageBackground
        source={backgroundImage}
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red" }}
        contentFit="cover"
      /> ...

